# Show only Published custom type posts with Custom Metaboxes in the WordPress Archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the [SitePoint post](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-post-series-plugin-for-wordpress/) to create a Post Series with Custom Post Type and have Custom Boxes for Post series number.

Below function is providing the list of all post published in the specific Taxonomy. Problem is it also listing the deleted & hidden posts as well:

```
function sitepoint_post_series_content_filter($content) {
$slug = "sitepoint-postseries";
if ($slug != get_post_type()) {
    return $content;
}

$post_series_list = get_option("post_series_" . get_the_ID() . "_ids", "");
$post_series_list_array = explode(',', $post_series_list);

$post_series_serial_number = array();

foreach ($post_series_list_array as $key => $value) {
    $serial_number = get_post_meta($value, "sitepoint-postseries-serial-number", true);
    $post_series_serial_number[$value] = $serial_number;
}

asort($post_series_serial_number);

$html = "<ul class='sitepoint-post-series'>";

foreach ($post_series_serial_number as $key => $value) {
    $post = get_post($key);
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $html = $html . "<li><h3><a href='" . get_permalink($key) . "'>" . $title . "</a></h3></li>";
}

$html = $html . "</ul>";
return $content . $html;
}

add_filter("the_content", "sitepoint_post_series_content_filter");
```

How can I exclude the Deleted & Hidden posts from this list.

Comment: did you check my last comment?

Comment: I got what is the issue i can solve this. There is no bug in that site

Comment: I have recently changed the code. I am dam sure this time this must be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code.

```
function sitepoint_post_series_content_filter($content) {
    $slug = "sitepoint-postseries";
    if ($slug != get_post_type()) {
        return $content;
    }

    $post_series_list = get_option("post_series_" . get_the_ID() . "_ids", "");
    $post_series_list_array = explode(',', $post_series_list);

    $post_series_serial_number = array();

    foreach ($post_series_list_array as $key => $value) {
        $serial_number = get_post_meta($value, "sitepoint-postseries-serial-number", true);
        $post_series_serial_number[$value] = $serial_number;
    }

    asort($post_series_serial_number);

    $finalArray = array();
    foreach ($post_series_serial_number as $keyPostID => $valueID) {
        if('publish' == get_post_status($keyPostID)){
            $finalArray[$keyPostID] = $keyPostID;
        }
    }


    $html = "<ul class='sitepoint-post-series'>";

    foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
        $post = get_post($key);
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $html = $html . "<li><h3><a href='" . get_permalink($key) . "'>" . $title . "</a></h3></li>";
    }

    $html = $html . "</ul>";
    return $content . $html;
}

add_filter("the_content", "sitepoint_post_series_content_filter");
```

Comment: can you echo get_post_status(get_the_ID()) and let me know what comes in the publish or published?

Comment: Even the deleted post is getting `publish`

Comment: can you double check the post type slug. if your post are deleted than their status must be trash. something is wrong please check the slug and instead of the get_the_ID() please put static id to check what happens.

Comment: slugs are good. There must be some errors in the overall code in creating this post-series & saving posts.

Comment: The title of the post is visible if the deleted post is in the Trash; if I delete permanently from Trash, there is a empty post is generating in the Archive list

Comment: I do no think so there is bug in the whole code because i did the condition that publish status post are only go ahead on home page are you looking at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172299/discussion-between-akshay-shah-and-theking).